# Flashlight App crashing every time in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, flashlight

I am trying to operate a flashlight app through TorchControl Class in Windows Phone application:
Here is my code

```
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredCamera)
    {
        DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);
        if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
        else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera {0} doesn't exist", desiredCamera));
    }


    async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
       var mediaDev = new MediaCapture();
       await mediaDev.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
       {
           StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
           PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
           AudioDeviceId = String.Empty,
           VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
       });
       var videoDev = mediaDev.VideoDeviceController;
       var tc = videoDev.TorchControl;
       if (tc.Supported)         
           tc.Enabled = true;
       mediaDev.Dispose();          
   }
```

But the problem is that the app crashes everytime i click on the button second time. I have been told to use the mediaDev.Dispose() method but it is also not working.
Here's the exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll WinRT information: The text associated with this error
>   code could not be found.

- This is showing while the text in "initializeasync" is highlighted

Comment: Whats the exception ?

Comment: "A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

WinRT information: The text associated with this error code could not be found." - This is showing while the text in "initializeasync" is highlighted

Comment: Consider editing the post to introduce these details.

Comment: Are you sure that second button click is done after "dispose" is called?

Answer (score 2):

MediaCapture will throw exception when it is re-initialized. To solve this issue, Just make sure you **do not initialize MediaCapture twice** when you navigate back to Camera page, or when you click the camera button.

```
    MediaCapture mediacapture = new MediaCapture();
    bool initialized;
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (initialized == false)
        {
            var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
            await mediacapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo,
                AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
            });
        }
        //Selecting Maximum resolution for Video Preview
        var maxPreviewResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height ? i1 : i2);
        //Selecting 4rd resolution setting
        var selectedPhotoResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).ElementAt(3);
        await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, selectedPhotoResolution);
        await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, maxPreviewResolution);
        // in my .xaml <CaptureElement Name="viewfinder" />
        viewfinder.Source = mediacapture;
        mediacapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
        await mediacapture.StartPreviewAsync(); 
        initialized = true;
    }
```

Also, make sure the **camera stops previewing** before you navigate to other page, or before camera starts preview again. There's no need to dispose MediaCapture.

```
    private async void GoBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        await mediacapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        //Not needed
        //mediacapture.Dispose();
    }
```

*GetCameraID* method credit to Romasz's blog. http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be related to multithreading: using the defaults (ie not changing the `SynchronizationContext`) calls to `await` will continue methods on another thread, something which is not always supported by graphics and media libraries (I have firsthand experience with SFML, WPF, and AutoCAD getting very crash-happy, to name a few). While the presence of an `InitializeAsync` method indicates otherwise, make sure disposal doesn't need to happen on the main thread or such.